# Slice conditional loop in Twig

Tags: arrays, twig, template-engine

I am using Pico CMS which in turn uses Twig as its template engine. I want to display 6 most recent pages that have a date defined in their meta, using a `for` loop. At the moment my loop looks like this: `{% for page in pages|slice(0,6) if page.date and date(page.date) < date() %}`, although the execution sequence here is not what I am after, since first `pages` returns an array of all pages, regardless of whether hey have a date defined or not, then it slices the first 6 items in the array, and only then it applies to these 6 items the condition that requires the page to have a date which is no later than today. I am quite new to Twig so I am not sure what syntax would allow me to slice an array *after* it has met the required condition. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution:

```
{% set limit = 6 %}
{% for page in pages if page.date and date(page.date) < date() and limit > 0 %}
    {# show your entry here #}
    {% set limit = limit - 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is ugly but should work. Change `limit` variable name if it colide with something else. If you want something better, you should write twig extension.

Comment: I don't mind ugly as long as it works, and it does! Thanks a lot!